# Hyperlink for every fixed text in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, hyperlink, shiny, concatenation

In the example below, I have to put an hyperlink for every 'ID' string in the column 3. The code below, however, cycles with `sapply` over every row of the column and grepl returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. How can I fix it?

```
 shinyApp(
        shinyUI(
            fluidPage(
                dataTableOutput('PM_output')
            )
        ),
        shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
            require(DT)
            dat <- read.table(text="Col1     Col2                  Col3
              Google   '5 lines description'   'ID273, ID288, ID299'
              Yahoo    '5 lines description'   'ID3, ID28, ID2'", header=T, strings=F)
            dat$Col3 <- sapply(grepl('ID',dat$Col3), function(x) 
                toString(tags$a(href=paste0("http://id=", x), x)))

            output$PM_output <- renderDataTable(expr = datatable(dat, escape=FALSE),
              options = list(autoWidth = T))
        })
    )
```

EDIT:
If Col3 is something like:

```
    Col3
    'Name=ID273, ID288, ID299;'
    'Name=ID273;'
```

How can I fix the code in a way like only the `'ID..'` part is an hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just just `paste0` for this. If you use a vector in `paste` the elements are concatenated separately for each item in the vector. In the example I created the hyperlink with `lapply` for each ID in each row that contains at least 1 ID string.

The `strsplit` functions creates a vector of the ID string, splitted at every comma. I added `trimws` to remove spaces arround the IDs.

Furthermore, you need to put the options inside the `datatable` function, and to be sure that you are not using `shiny`'s `dataTableOutput` and `renderDataTable` function I prefer to put `DT::` before these functions.

**Working example**

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      DT::dataTableOutput('PM_output')
    )
  ),
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    dat <- read.table(text="Col1     Col2                  Col3
              Google   '5 lines description'   'ID273, ID288, ID299'
              Yahoo    '5 lines description'   'ID3, ID28, ID2'", header=T, strings=F)
    dat$Col3[grepl('ID',dat$Col3)] = lapply(dat$Col3[grepl('ID',dat$Col3)], function(x)paste0("<a href=\"http://id=", trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ',',fixed=T))), "\">", trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ',',fixed=T))),"</a>"))

    output$PM_output <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(dat, escape=FALSE, options = list(autoWidth = T))})
  })
)
```

**Edit**

If I understand it right your requested output for line 1 is:

`"Name=<a href=\"http://id=ID273\">ID273</a>,<a href=\"http://id=ID288\">ID288</a>,<a href=\"http://id=ID299\">ID299</a>;"`

You can create this with:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Col1     Col2                  Col3
              Google   '5 lines description'   'Name=ID273, ID288, ID299;'
                  Yahoo    '5 lines description'   'Name=ID3, ID28, ID2;'", header=T, strings=F)
dat$Col3=lapply(gsub("Name=|;", "", dat$Col3[grepl('ID',dat$Col3)]), function(x)paste0("<a href=\"http://id=", trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ',',fixed=T))), "\">", trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ',',fixed=T))),"</a>", collapse=','))
dat$Col3=paste0('Name=',dat$Col3,';')
```